# Gmail Extension, sendMessage to background from page context

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I'm building an extension to integrate with Gmail and integrating with Gmail by injecting the gmail.js into the page context, as shown here: https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail-chrome-extension-boilerplate/blob/master/content.js

That seems to be the only obvious way to make use of some globals that Google is embedding on the page.

So now, I need to get back to some of the functionality of the extension. Under normal conditions (operating from a content script), I would send a message to the background script, but is that even possible from the context of the tab itself?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry...this has some more detail: https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail-chrome-extension-boilerplate/issues/2

Comment: Aha, now I get it. You need to message your background from page context.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A page-context script cannot, indeed, use Chrome API.
It can, however, dispatch DOM events that can be caught by the content script.

There is an example in the documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication). Besides using `window.postMessage`, you can [dispatch custom events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417121/is-there-any-way-of-passing-additional-data-via-custom-events).

So, you need to make your content script to work like a proxy between page context and background. Something along these lines:

```
// Content script
//Listen for the event
window.addEventListener("PassToBackground", function(evt) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(evt.detail);
}, false);

// Page context
var message = {/* whatever */};
var event = new CustomEvent("PassToBackground", {detail: message});
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You can generalize this to pass an answer back.

Comment: @Xan could you please tell how I would make the script that comes from the page to call the content-script with a callback? Let's say I want to send an http request, and I want the extension to do it for me due to CORS errors. So I'll need to know within my app what the response will be... How would I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Just to expand on this a bit, when using gmail.js, in order to get a message from `main.js` to your extension page, you need to use your content script as an intermediary. This diagram will hopefully illustrate.

```
main.js
 |
 | window.postMessage();
 |
 V
content.js //window.addEventListener("message", callback, false);
 |
 | chrome.runtime.sendMessage();
 |
 V
background.js //chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(callback);
```