# Can a website I'm visiting have access to a global variable added by a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Let's say I have a Chrome extension adding some JS code to each visited page (this is quite common with `content_scripts`):

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": ["run.js"],
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
    ...
}
```

Let' say the `run.js` has a global `templates` variable:

```
var templates = {0: 'hello world', 1: 'bye bye'}; // default templates

chrome.storage.sync.get("templates", function(obj) {
    templates = obj.templates;
});

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    // add template to textarea if a specific key is pressed
}
```

Question: **can a website I'm visiting scrape all my personal data stored in my templates (because it's in a global variable `templates`), and send it via AJAX to their server?** If so, how?

Or is it impossible because there is an isolation wall between Chrome extension content_scripts' variables and the page's variables?

Comment: Note: I already read: [Do content scripts run in the same isolated world, or in separate isolated worlds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333350/do-content-scripts-run-in-the-same-isolated-world-or-in-separate-isolated-world) but it's unclear what happens in the specific case I described.

Answer (score 2):

#### Isolated Worlds

No, the context scripts are sandboxed and can only access the DOM, as you can read [on the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment):

> Content scripts live in an isolated world, allowing a content script to makes changes to its JavaScript environment without conflicting with the page or additional content scripts.

The website you inject `run.js` to won't be able to access `templates`.

Actually, even if you do `window.templates = templates` in `run.js`, the injected page will get `undefined` if it tries to access it.

#### ️ Practical Example

Let's say you have a Chrome extension that injects a script on the currently active tab when you press the browser action button that shows a popup on the page. If that popup has already been injected before, you want to just call a `toggle` method on it.

You could have something like this on your injected script:

```
import { Popup } from './components/popup.component';

const popup = window.POPUP;

if (popup) {
    popup.toggle();
} else {
    window.POPUP = new Popup();
}
```

Then:

- The first time this is injected, `window.POPUP`, in the world of the context scripts, would be `undefined`, so we will create a new `Popup` instance and assign it to `window.POPUP`, again, in the context scripts' world.
- The second and subsequent times this is injected, `window.POPUP`, in the world of the context scripts, would already have a value and we will just call `popup.toggle()`.
- If a script on the injected page tries to access `window.POPUP` anytime, in its own world, it will get `undefined`.
- If the injected page had a `window.POPUP = true`, the content script will still get `undefined` when accessing `window.POPUP` for the first time, as those two `window.POPUP` live in separated worlds.

Comment: @Basj Sorry, I copied the wrong text from the docs. Please, take a look now. I have also added a practical example of what would happen when either the context script or the injected page try to access stuff from the other.