# How to get window variable from script tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I need to get the **window.configData**, variable that is inside a script tag. There are multiple script tags in my HTML code. But I need to get only the script tag that contains the **window.configData** variable.
I know this can be done using**document.scripts / document.getElementsByTagName('script')**, and searching for required variable.

I need to get this element  in a single line, so as to pass it as variable to the content script in chrome extension.
Below is the code of my content script.

```
function getPageDetails(jsonValueToFind, callback) { 
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code:
            "document.defaultView.configData"
        }, function(result) {
    var value = result[0];
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
        callback({
            url: tabs[0].url,
            title: tabs[0].title,
            jsonValue: value
        });
    });
});
```

}

I need to pass this variable to the code section of content script.
Can anybody suggest me how to acheive this

Answer (score 0):

Parsing source code of the page to dig out variables from the `window` of the page is probably not a good idea. What if it's not a simple assignment? What if a `<script>` tag self-deletes?

As you probably noticed already, if you try to evaluate `window.configData` in the content script's context, it will return `undefined`.

The reason for this is [the isolated world concept](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment): the target page will have 2 independent JS contexts attached, one for the page (that has `configData`) and your content script's context. `window` objects are not the same.

To access the page's object, you need to execute your code in the page's context. It's possible if you [inject a `<script>` tag with your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script). Then, you can [pass the data to your content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838804/gmail-extension-sendmessage-to-background-from-page-context/25847017#25847017) or write it in the DOM somewhere where it's accessible by the content script.

```
+-----------------+ -(executeScript)-> +----------------+ --(<script>)---> +-------------+
| Background page |                    | Content script |                  | Page script |
+-----------------+ <--(sendMessage)-- +----------------+ <-(CustomEvent)- +-------------+
```

Since data collection is going to be asynchronous, you can't rely on return value of `executeScript` - you'll need to pass a message back.

Because of that, maybe even better to include a content script that always loads (through manifest) and collects data preemptively, and then the background page can query it:

```
                                       +----------------+ --(<script>)---> +-------------+
                                       |                |                  | Page script |
                                       | Content script | <-(CustomEvent)- +-------------+
                                       | (in manifest)  |
+-----------------+ --(sendMessage)--> |                |
| Background page |                    |                |
+-----------------+ <--(sendResponse)- +----------------+
```

[I answered about it in detail  before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140443/executing-code-at-page-level-from-background-js-and-returning-the-value/26141393#26141393).

Answer (score -2):

Just complement the script, where your window.configData is implement, with an onload handler and id.

```
var script document.getelementbyid("scriptid");
script.onload= function(){ window.configData;  }
```