# Is it possible to message the dev-tools panel from within inspectedWindow.eval?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I have been reading over the chrome extension [message passing documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), but I cannot seem to establish communication from within the inspected window.

For example,

```
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval('function() {  
      .
      . 
      .
     /* send message to dev-tools panel */ 
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({foo:"foo"});<-- Uncaught Error: Invalid arguments to connect. Why is the extensionId required within chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval? This made me step back and ask the question.
}')
```

I have tried leveraging both background and content scripts to listen for these messages, but nothing seems to trigger. My actual implementation is listening for WebSocket traffic, I left that out for brevity. I am able to listen to each request/response, however I cannot seem to establish communication within inspectedWindow.eval. In the end, my goal is to simply communicate with my dev-tools panel so I can update the UI.

**Update**

I found an interesting repo from someone that faced a similar issue. They however did not seem to find a valid solution. Could it be that this sort of messaging is not allowed by design?

https://github.com/thomasboyt/injectedWindow.eval-communication-sadness

Comment: do you want to simply log something in the current page's editor? use chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:'console.log("stuff") or anything else'})

Comment: @Thouartamazing I don't have access to chrome.tabs from inside the inspected window. But to answer your question, I think I need some sort of messaging construct that can pass data back and forth. With that said, console.log will not do the trick in this instance.

Comment: i dont understand exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @Thouartamazing I have updated the question with an example I stumbled across in my search. This is directly inline with what I am doing in my current implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you considered using a content script.

In that case, you can [raise a custom DOM event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25847017/934239), and the content script will be able to process it.

```
// Content script
window.addEventListener("RebroadcastExtensionMessage", function(evt) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(evt.detail);
}, false);

// Eval'd code
var message = {/* whatever */};
var event = new CustomEvent("RebroadcastExtensionMessage", {detail: message});
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

The downside, of course, is that the page can listen in on those events if it so chooses as well as spoof them. If that's a serious concern, you can include nonces into event names and messages originating from dev tools. But then again, a *really* hostile page can override `CustomEvent`.. In a way, this is not a solvable problem, since anything you `inspectedWindow.eval()` fully shares context (and API access) with the page.

Comment: Your solution worked as expected! Thank you for the help.