# How to send information from window to the devtool in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

In my app I have a namespaced application and there's information or metadata `myApp` carries on it that might be useful to devpane.

```
window.myApp = new App();
```

1. How can I relay or send the following information to the `devtool.js`?

   ```
   window.myApp.metadata; // information
   ```
2. And can I send a request from the devtool with a function that customizes the serialization of that metadata?

I've seen similar posts with the solution below, which returns `null` when I tried it.

```
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("window.myApp", {
  useContentScriptContext: true
})
```

NOTE: If a sample template can be provided that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I've solved this. It feels more complicated than necessary, but it does work.

**In the context of the inspected window**

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500588/is-it-possible-to-message-the-dev-tools-panel-from-within-inspectedwindow-eval/32506133).

This is where you've got access to `window.myApp.metadata` and can put it into the data object.

```
var event = new CustomEvent("RebroadcastExtensionMessage", {data: ""});
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

**In the content script**

This just forwards the data to the background page.

```
window.addEventListener("RebroadcastExtensionMessage", function(evt) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(evt)
}, false);
```

**In the background page**

Based on the [Chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#injecting).

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(devToolsConnection) {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        devToolsConnection.postMessage(request)
    });
})
```

**In devtools.js**

```
var backgroundPageConnection = chrome.runtime.connect({
    name: "devtools-page"
});

backgroundPageConnection.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    // Data has arrived in devtools page!!
});
```

Comment: The documentation for [Messaging from Injected Scripts to the DevTools Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#evaluated-scripts-to-devtools) suggests the same technique, but uses the `window.postMessage` API instead of a `CustomEvent`. It also does suggest that you have to go via the content script and background page to do this, so IT IS necessary, given the current architecture. Good answer.

Comment: so put {data: window.myApp.metadata} in the event and this will show up on background?

Comment: @MattZeunert but can i use devtool.js to house the first script and sends window.myApp? or does the client application have to voluntarily build and send that event?

Comment: @MattZeunert nm, i guess you still have to inject code, thanks matty

Comment: Yeah, only code that's been injected into the page has access to the correct `window` object.