# How to check if a Firefox WebExtension is installed or not with page JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mozilla, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have developed a WebExtension for Firefox and my website works with the extension as a prerequisite. I need to check programmatically whether the extension is installed or not and if not ask the user to install it.

I am not able to find a way how to check this operation of whether my extension is already installed in the user's browser.

Editor note: Methods available in Firefox differ from those [available in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed), so this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Why the google-chrome-extension tag? Your question seems to be about Firefox.

Comment: I believe your extension can add a global variable to the page. Add a very specifically named global variable and, in your page, check if it exists. Something like `window.my-ext-name-a1b2c34d = true` in your extention, and then check `if (window.my-ext-name-a1b2c34d)` on your website

Comment: @TKoL That would not work naively

Comment: Closing as duplicate of a canonical Chrome question; WebExtensions don't differ significantly enough from the Chrome model in this respect.

Comment: @Xan This question is not duplicate to Chrome. There are ways for chrome to check if an extension is installed or not. I am interested in this type of check for FIREFOX.

Comment: Are you aware that, with exception of small differences, Firefox extensions behave the same way? All of the answers (at least highly voted ones) apply. And I don't think there's a mechanism available only in Firefox.

Comment: On the other hand, you do mention Firefox AddOn SDK, which is different from WebExtensions. Can you show your manifest?

Comment: Firefox add on SDK , I added by mistake. I know both chrome and FF follow web extensions api. I am not talking about developing a FF extension. The question is to find ways to detect an extension. Pretty clear.

Comment: Indeed. Pretty clear. You'll need to implement changes to your extensions to make it cooperate with the webpage. As I said, everything in the linked question applies, and I am unaware of any radically different methods specific to FF. Still a duplicate.

Comment: Here's an FF specific sample: https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/page-to-extension-messaging

Comment: You know what, I'll reopen this. Simply because possibilities in FF are smaller than in Chrome (I didn't know it doesn't currently support `externally_connectable`), it's worth noting it here.

Comment: Okay, @Maninder, there's no shame in admitting wrongs. I looked more deeply into it and Firefox is _shockingly_ different from Chrome in this regard. Thanks for actually bringing this question up, even though it would probably be helpful if you mentioned that some methods don't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Important note to begin with: **A page can't query if an extension is installed without explicit help from the extension.** This is done to prevent browser fingerprinting and/or preventing sites from denying content if certain extensions are installed.

WebExtensions are largely built upon the same principles as Chrome extensions. As such, this question is relevant: [Check whether user has a Chrome extension installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed).

However, **some of the best methods available in Chrome are currently unavailable in Firefox**:

- You can't use [**external messaging from a webpage**](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external-webpage) (through `externally_connectable`) as it's not available in FF.
- You can't [**use web-accessible resources** for checking presence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27930310/934239) since Firefox [intentionally shields them from fingerprinting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources):

> The files will then be available using a URL like:

> ```
> moz-extension://<random-UUID>/<path/to/resource>
> ```

> This UUID is **randomly generated for every browser instance** and is not your extension's ID. This prevents websites from fingerprinting the extensions a user has installed.

As such, what are your options? The page can't talk directly to the extension context (background), and the background can't directly affect the page; you need a [Content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts) to interact with the page content.

How can page code and a content script communicate? They are isolated from each other unless content script does something about it.

First off, generic tricks that work in both FF and Chrome:

- You can [**create or modify a DOM element**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6293601/934239) on the page from a content script and look for those modifications in the page.

  ```
    // Content script
    let beacon = document.createElement("div");
    beacon.classname = browser.runtime.id;
    document.body.appendChild(beacon);

    // Page script
    // Make sure this runs after the extension code
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("expected-extension-id").length) {
      // Installed
    } else {
      // Not installed
    }
  ```
- You can **use `postMessage` to communicate** between contexts, though it's clunky to use as a bidirectional channel.

  Here's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_the_web_page) and [sample WebExtension](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/page-to-extension-messaging).

  ```
    // Content script code
    window.postMessage({
      direction: "from-content-script",
      message: "Message from extension"
    }, "*");

    // Page code
    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
      if (event.source == window &&
          event.data.direction &&
          event.data.direction == "from-content-script") {
        // Assume extension is now installed
      }
    });
  ```
- You can **[use custom DOM events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838804/gmail-extension-sendmessage-to-background-from-page-context/25847017#25847017)** in a similar way.

There are interesting Firefox-specific approaches as well:

- You can [**share code with the page**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts) using `exportFunction` or `cloneInto`:

  ```
    // Content script
    function usefulFunction() {
      /* ... */
    }

    const extensionInterface = {
      usefulFunction
    }
    window.wrappedJSObject.extensionInterface = 
      cloneInto(extensionInterface, window, {cloneFunctions: true});

    // Page code
    if (typeof window.extensionInterface !== "undefined") {
      // Installed
      window.extensionInterface.usefulFunction();
    } else {
      // Not installed
    }
  ```