# Programmatically invoke tab capture throws exception

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a listener defined in my content script in chrome extension:

```
document.addEventListener("startRecording", function(data) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'action' : 'captureCurrentTab'});
});
```

and have a function defined in my extension.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(

function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
       if (request.action == "captureCurrentTab"){

        captureCurrentTab();
     }
 });

function captureCurrentTab() {

    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabCapture.capture(MediaStreamConstraint, handleCapture);
    });
}

var MediaStreamConstraint = {
            //audio: true,
            video: true,
            videoConstraints: {
                mandatory: {
                    chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
                    minWidth: 1920,
                    maxWidth: 1920,
                    minHeight: 1080,
                    maxHeight: 1080
                }
            }
        };

function handleCapture(stream) {

    console.log('content captured');
    console.log("Adding Stream: ", stream);

}
```

but when i send message to start recording from my web application like this:

```
var event = document.createEvent('Event');
            event.initEvent('startRecording');
            document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

then extension throws exceptions:

1) Error in response to tabCapture.capture: MediaStream is mandatory.
2) Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabCapture.capture: Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab permission). Chrome pages cannot be captured.

Here are the permissions i have supplied:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabCapture",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*" ,
    "http://localhost:1615/*"
  ]
```

But when I click on my extension button and repeat the same process (send message for recording) then everything works fine. I don't know why I have to click extension button every time to start capturing screen.
How can I start it automatically?

I have also defined shortcut keys for my extension. When I press them before sending message for recording then everything works fine. but when I triggered/simulate them from my application then again end up with same exception.

Please help.

Comment: What causes the `startRecording` event in the document? If it's not an explicit user gesture, then it's not considered "invoked" and will fail.

Comment: I have a button in my application. I have this code on my button click event:

var event = document.createEvent('Event');
            event.initEvent('startRecording');
            document.dispatchEvent(event);

Comment: You are new here; hint: you can and should **edit** your question with additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that Chrome loses track of the fact that this event was initiated with a click. It is therefore not "invoked".

You should instead bind a `click` event listener in your content script code/context, and send the message from there directly. I think it should be enough for Chrome to accept that as invocation by the user.

---

Alternatively, direct sending of a message to the extension bypassing the content script may work. This is achievable with [`"externally_connectable"` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24243290/934239) ([docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage)).

Comment: This is not working :( same exceptions occurred when accessed my internal method directly from my application .

Comment: Do you mean the first or the second method I mentioned?

Comment: Strange. Can you update your question with code from attempting the first method (click listener in content script)?